# Android: Placing button relative to ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to make a part of a bitmap clickable and my layout looks like this:

```
________________________________
|             #####             |
|             #####             |
|      ___________________      |
|      |                 |      |
|      |                 |      |
|      |      image      |      |
|      |                 |      |
|      |                 |      |
|      ___________________      |
________________________________
```

I thought the easiest way to this would be to place a button over the image with a relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But I haven't figured out how to get the button to align with the upper left corner of the image (instead of the upper left corner of the relative layout, as it does now). Is this possible with a relative layout?

Suggestions for other approaches are also welcome, I considered this:
http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/
But it seems a bit of an overkill for my simple rectangle area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my google-fu improved and thanks to asenovm I figured it out! The imageview has a android:adjustViewBounds property, which is by default set to false. Setting it to true adjusts the imageviews bounds to the image, so that alignLeft and alignTop work correctly for the button.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop = "@id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop = "@id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I should have added that the image gets scaled to fit into the left-over space, so the space left and right to the image is not padding set by me. So even with align, the button gets aligned with the relative layout element instead of the actual size of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You  can also use

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image1" 
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image2t"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/image3"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/image4"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/image4"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
```